# Restarting threads in forked process

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, fork

I know there is no standard way of forking a multithreaded process. However, one thing come into my mind, which is that since the forked process is the exact replica or the original process, the thread stacks would be there.

Does anyone have any idea of how to restart the threads from their last execution state in the forked process. For simplicity, we can assume that there were no acquired locks at the time of forking. Say for example, forking was done between two barriers.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any particular situation where the advantages of this would outweigh the complexity of such a setup (that is, mixing multithreading and multiprocessing)?

Comment: Basically I want to checkpoint a mulithreaded process by forking it, but stopping the forked process. Then when anything goes wrong, I can execute my program from the last checkpoint (forked process).

Comment: MetallicPriest, look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing If you will be able to make a checkpoint of multithreaded application and if you have a way of loading checkpointed state into CPU, then you can restore the saved state twice. As I understand, checkpointing needs kernel support OR requests an external (to the process) debugger. Also I should say that there can be no any universal checkpointing solution, and program to be checkpointed has a lot of limits (e.g. on network connections) to be restored fully.

Comment: +1 to @osgx. Do not use fork() for this. It's much better to save your application state explicitly and load it on restart.

Comment: blaze, the overhead of storing 4GB (and even more on 64 bit) is very large. I'm using fork because of its efficient copy on write mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threads execution state is not only the data in stack. It is also set of CPU registers, which is lost.

`do_fork()` system call just don't copy any thread other from thread, which executes a syscall [do_fork](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/kernel/fork.c#L1403) -> [copy_process](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/kernel/fork.c#L994) and there is a single call to copy_thread at [line 1181](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/kernel/fork.c#L1181)

```
retval = copy_thread(clone_flags, stack_start, stack_size, p, regs);
```

Comment: Say I save the context of threads (CPU registers) by using getcontext before forking. Then, any idea of how to restart them?

Comment: If there's a `getcontext`, is there also a `setcontext`? It seems kind of pointless to have one without the other.

Comment: MetallicPriest, I think, you should do a checkpointing from another process, which will ptrace your process. Also, the restoring of threads is not an easy task.

Comment: Yes there is a setcontext too!

Comment: In addition to CPU state, thread group structure is also lost.

Basically, before fork() there are several task_structs, after fork() --
only one.

Creating task_struct is something like clone(CLONE_THREAD) and
still you need to restore CPU state.

Comment: osgx, does ptrace works with multithreaded processes? I have used it for single threaded processes, but I'm not sure if it works with multithreaded ones.

Comment: adobriyan, one thing that comes in my mind is to note down the address of the task_structs and recreate the threads and then set context to the last execution state. Do you think it will work?

Comment: Yes, ptrace works with multithreaded. Just use TID instead of PID. TIDs for PID N are listed in /proc/N/task folder.

Comment: MetallicPriest, after getcontext, thread should not run (continue computation) until the stack is copied into another place.

Comment: osgx, perhaps i need to modify the do_fork method to copy the threads. Already I'm starting to get a headache thinking about this :(! Will have to dig very deep into it!

Comment: You should not create a full clone of multithreaded process with `fork()`. You need something new syscall (or something experimental, like listed at  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing).

Comment: Hey osgx, do you know Solaris has a function to do just that by the name of forkall? I'm so happy to know about that :)!

Comment: Hey, MetallicPriest, do you know that Solaris is cheating here, as your question labeled Linux? http://linux.die.net/man/3/fork "The addition of the forkall() function to the standard *was considered and* **rejected.** " Also, http://www.mail-archive.com/opensolaris-code@opensolaris.org/msg02251.html Good link form the list discussion is to openVZ wiki http://wiki.openvz.org/Checkpointing_internals - they have a live migration and a lot of problems connected to this.

Answer (score 1):

Guess What? Solaris already has such a function by the name of **[forkall](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2241/forkall-2/index.html)**! Would love to see a port of it in Linux!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about [continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation). I saw some hits on google (I asked for "continuation c"), but I can't recomend any link, since I don't know your specific needs.